# In Laravel when working with HTML form arrays and dynamic inputs, how can I set custom validation messages?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel version 5.3.  I have a number of fields on a page, some of which are dynamically added using JavaScript.  The format of the fields is:

`<input type="text" name="questions[1][friendly_name]" value="What is your name?">`

I have some validation inside my Store Request to ensure these fields are present:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [        
        'questions.*.friendly_name' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

This is working fine.  The problem is the message it outputs is a little ugly:

> The questions.1.friendly_name field is required.
>
> The questions.2.friendly_name field is required.
>
> The questions.3.friendly_name field is required.

To change the questions, I would think (and it appears that way in the documentation) that you'd amend the `messages` method in the Store Request as follows:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'questions.*.friendly_name' => [
            'required' => "The Question Name is required for all questions, one has been omitted."
        ],
    ];
}
```

This is where the problem is - the above message is being ignored and not outputted.

So, my question: how can I handle messages for validation with dynamic field sets?

Note: the above code is truncated.  I am using multiple arrays, such as: `questions[1][answers[3][answer_plain]`.  To my knowledge, this shouldn't make any difference, but thought I'd mention it just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
foreach($this->request->get('question') as $questionKey => $questionValue){
 $message['question.'. $questionKey . '.required'] = 'Question ' . ($questionKey+1) . ' is Required';
}
```

Since you've multi-dimensional data, you will have to implement nested foreach to accomplish custom error messaging issue.

See, if that helps.

Comment: The documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation) specifically mentions the wildcard syntax for messages and validation rules to prevent the need for looping through messages in this way though.  It seems very strange to be able to set a rule the same way as any other rule, but not to be able to define a message for it.

Comment: Even for rules I'd to made a foreach loop to define rules.

Answer (score 0):

To Validate all the fields with custom error message individually, Creating validator manually is the best solution so that messages with dynamic fields can be set individually.

**step-1:**

```
use Validator; (after namespace of any controller where validation is needed)
```

**step-2:**

Add a method (suppose the method name check_data()). And inside the following code will be placed....

```
public function check_data(Request $request){

//Rules for form fields
$rules = array(
    'training_id' =>'required',
    'survey_name' =>'required',
    'question' =>'required',
    'answer_option' =>'required'
);

//Custom message for individual fields
$messages = array(
    'training_id.required' => 'Training Id should not be empty...',
    'survey_name.required' => 'Survey Name  is Essential...',
    'question.required' => 'Question is urgent...',
    'answer_option.required' => 'Answer option can be any one but required...'

);

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

//Check for validation
if ($validator->fails()) {
    //if validation fails
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
} else {
    //Validation is successful and do as you wish
    return "All data are validated !!";

}




}
```

Hopefully, It will work

Comment: The question is based around HTML input arrays, which weren't validating as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This must work properly: Currently I had checked on laravel 5.8.*.

public function messages()
        {
            return [
                'questions.*.friendly_name.required' => 'The Question Name is required for all questions, one has been omitted.'
    
            ];
        }
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.